# Cannot connect to back end, my path/file is not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

How do I configure my file correctly?

I am trying to submit a form, and when I submit it I am getting a 404 error that my path/file is not found.

The exact error is:

```
xhr.js:175 POST http://localhost:1337/mail 404 (Not Found)
```

My app.js file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var mail = require('./routes/mail');
var app = express();

app.use('/mail', mail);
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(express.static('dist/img'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
console.log('Port 1337 is listening');
```

My mail.js file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var mail = express.Router();

mail.get('/:name/:email/:phone:/message', function(req, res){
    console.log('in function');
});

console.log('Made it to mail');

module.exports = mail;
```

The function that sends the code from a jsx file is:

```
handleClick(e){
    const name = this.state.name;
    const email = this.state.email;
    const phone = this.state.phone;
    const message = this.state.message;
    e.preventDefault();
    if(name === "" | email === "" | phone === "" | message === ""){
        return;
    }else{
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/mail',
            data: {name, email, phone, message}
        });
    }

}
```

The header shows the following:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1337/mail
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:1337
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:18
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 23 Jan 2017 21:17:15 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:85
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:1337
Origin:http://localhost:1337
Referer:http://localhost:1337/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
view source
{name: "Username", email: "user@gmail.com", phone: "1234567891", message: "testing"}
```

When I run gulp, I do get the console message that it 'Made it to mail'. But when I submit the form, it gives me the error "POST http://localhost:1337/mail 404 (Not Found)".

My directory is set up as:

```
root/
...dist/ (this is where my client.min.js file is where all my front end code is)
...routes/
app.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to read the [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) documentation on how to define routes.
Also you do not seem to understand the difference between request body (the data you passed to axios data property) and url (/mail/....)

The route you have defined will catch ONLY **GET** REQUESTS but you're doing **POST** request from axios, and you do not have any route for a **POST** request

Also what you have defined will only catch for example url like this `/mail/john/blablamail/blablaphone/blablamessage` since what you did:

```
app.use('/mail', mail);
//...
mail.get('/:name/:email/:phone/:message',...);
```

can be simplyfied to this:

```
app.get('/mail/:name/:email/:phone:/message',..);
```

what you are doing is good for dynamic url which you don't seem to need.
Example is:

```
// assume url /users/123
app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.id); // output = 123
});
```

What you need instead is **POST** `app.post(...);` like this:

```
app.post('/mail', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body); 
    // -> {name: "Username", email: "user@gmail.com", phone: "1234567891", message: "testing"}
});
```

**EDIT**

And one more thing. In order for the req.body to be js object you gonna need [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to parse the json data. Specificly this line `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: I am hesitant to say "Thank you so much" because I don't know if it is proper etiquette for stack overflow but I have to. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me and get me on the right path. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can say *Thank you* in a comment :) I'm glad I could help you.